# Forcing the use of the Host ICE Candidate in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

Is anyone aware of a way I could force WebRTC to only try ICE connection establishment via the host candidate?

Right now, I'm looking at non-intrusive ways, such as filtering outgoing traffic to block STUN/TURN servers during ICE candidate gathering. However, this is causing the gathering process to take quite long as this particular stack does not support trickle ICE. If I can do this with only a network change, that would be ideal (whereby any device behind this network must use the host candidate).

Without trickle ICE, I'm wondering if there is a way to filter out the STUN/TURN addresses while also setting the ICE candidate gathering timeout to a low value. This would cause STUN/TURN candidates to be put into a 'Failed' state, and then only the host candidate would inevitable be sent over.

Comment: the obvious answer is "dont configure stun/turn", alternatively filter any srflx/relay candidates in onicecandidate and strip them from the SDP. Not sure i understand the question though.

Comment: Hey Philipp. We're trying to accomplish this passively, without any code changes. I don't think there is any way to do this other than to block the STUN/TURN addresses at the router. The unfortunate consequence is that without trickle ICE, time to media takes quite a long time (WebRTC would have to wait for those STUN/TURN requests to timeout). My question was more of a shot in the dark I suppose - hoping I missed something simple.

Comment: sadly no. Everyone has a candidate filter in their JS code. Or the server code when you're trickling :-)

Comment: I thought as much. Ah, this may be a little more troublesome than I originally hoped for. Trickle ICE is a good thing :). If it was supported, it would be as easy as blocking STUN/TURN addresses.

Comment: This is really hacky, but you could return a negative response to the requests! For TURN you could MITM and deny the allocation (not an option if you are doing TLS though). For STUN binding maybe respond with a bogus response (127.0.0.1 5000) or something like that. It shouldn't the other side that bad to have an invalid srflx candidate.